# Retrieve the artwork from an MP3/m4a file and store it as a regular jpg?

Tags: ruby, mp3, jpeg

I am looking for a way to retrieve the artwork from a large amount of mp3 files and store the artwork as jpg files in a folder. The only gem I am aware of able to read mp3 data is `mp3info` and the documentation only says that it can write images to the mp3 not retrieve the data from the mp3, are there any gems that give this capability?

Comment: I'm currently trying to do this as well, but I used taglib. I'm able to pull the tags, but can't turn them into a JPG. Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting it. As I said above, I ended up using taglib, and used [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/) to store the files in my fs.

If you follow the documentation on https://robinst.github.io/taglib-ruby/, you would use:

```
file = TagLib::MPEG::File.new(file)
  id3v2_tag = file.id3v2_tag
  cover = id3v2_tag.frame_list('APIC').first
file.close
```

to grab the picture. Then create a new file to write the data:

```
newfile = File.new('temp.jpg', 'w+')
  newfile.write(cover.picture.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
newfile.close
```

Then use Carrierwave, Paperclip, or whatever to store it somewhere. Hope this helps.